# Exit shell script if psql throws error in exectuting sql scripts

Tags: bash, postgresql, shell

I have below shell script

```
#! /bin/sh

for file in $(ls -l scripts/*.sql | awk '{print $NF}'); do 
 psql -h host -d db -U user -p port -f $file;
 result=$?
 if [ $result -ne 0 ] 
   then
   exit 1
 fi
done
```

$result always comes 0 even if I add some error to sql file. I want to exit shell script if any sql script throws error. Am I missing something in catching the error of last executed statement

Comment: Don't use `ls`  and `$()` just loop through the globs.

Comment: try `-b` Print failed SQL commands to standard error output. This is equivalent to setting the variable ECHO to errors.

Comment: You don't need to test the exit status as well.

Comment: You can verify your script via    https://shellcheck.net

Comment: @Jetchisel Thanks this link is useful to update script specially around legacy code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try: `psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -f $file`

This makes psql stopping at first SQL error and returning a non-zero return code in this case.